# news ticker failed to restart after hover

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with a demo jquery news ticker . it is working good. and when i am hover on news ticker then it is going to stop.
but after this it is not scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdjs2/

```
$(function() {
    function tick(){
       $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function () {  $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
        }
        var timeSet = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 1000);
        $('#ticker').hover(function() { 
                    $('#ticker  li:first').stop();         
                        clearInterval(timeSet);   
                }, tick());    
        tick();
});
```

Comment: JSfiddle demo is not working...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kdjs2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(+1 this is useful example for me) On hover toggle you set `tick();` function and it works a time, You should set `setInterval` function, then it works per second.

```
$('#ticker').hover(function () {
    $('#ticker  li:first').stop();
    clearInterval(timeSet);
}, function () {
    timeSet = setInterval(function () {
        tick();
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdjs2/7/